# Django Column 'id' cannot be null

Tags: django, django-models, django-database

I am having a weird problem with my mysql database and django.

I created an app with a model imported from an existing database with inspectdb. It was working fine until yesterday I removed the django automatically created tables (django_*, auth_*, site_*). I did that because it was preventing my model to validate when I added my app in the installed apps.

Now today I tried inserting a new record in my database and I get the following error :

```
Django Version:     1.3
Exception Type:     IntegrityError
Exception Value: (1048, "Column 'asset_id' cannot be null")
```

The field is a primary key and it's supposed to be auto_increment so I don't give a value to it when I create a new record.

Can someone point me what's going on here ?

EDIT : I partly figured out the problem : somehow all my auto_increment proprities were removed from my database. How did that happen ?

Comment: I do not know much about mysql database structure, but i guess you remove tables directly from database, so you may accidentally delete one of mysql tables that keep track of unique key id sequences... So better you chech you DBMS structure integrity...

Comment: Well, I rebuilded my database from scratch so now it's ok. I won't remove any more tables from now on !

Comment: This is related to your prevous question... You shouldn't have removed the **tables**, but the **models** that django generated for you using `inspectdb`. The tables are there to support django's own models. The missingo point was that if any other model had a FK to the django ones, you 'd have changed the reference from the "inspected" one to the "django" one (importing etc)

Comment: I did remove only the models actually..

Comment: "Column 'asset_id' cannot be null" -- that DOES NOT sound like a PK with auto_increment... it sounds like a foreign key field that's not allowed to be NULL in your DB, but somehow you've imported a row in which it's NULL.

Comment: asset_id is a PK, that I'm sure of

Answer (score 0):

Check your generated models, and ensure that the "auto_increment" columns correspond with fields marked with the `primary_key=True` option.

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to save your object model, before obtain `id` property.